# What to use as password when registering a user via Google OAuth?

Tags: authentication, oauth, passwords, google-oauth, token

I have a sign-up page that uses email and password.

I store the email and (salted, hashed) password in the database.

I'm now adding Google OAuth to my sign-up page.

For the main advantage being that user now shouldn't have to pick a password.

When the user authenticates and I receive the user's Google profile, what exactly do use now as their "password"? The profile object looks like this:

```js
{
  Ca: '123456789...',
  wc: {
    token_type: 'Bearer',
    access_token: 'abc.123.ABCabc..........',
    scope: 'email profile ...',
    login_hint: '...',
    expires_in: 3599,
    id_token: '......',
    session_state: { ... },
    first_issued_at: ...,
    expires_at: ...,
    ...
  },
  googleId: ...,
  tokenObj: { ... },
  profileObj: { googleId: ..., name: ..., },
}
```

I was inclined to use "access_token" or "id_token" as password but then there's "expires_at" field that suggests they might change over time and be of no use in future login attempts.

Would they? If so, what else should I choose as the user's password that won't change and allow to me authenticate them every time they login via Google OAuth?